# installed anaconda but not able to find anaconda navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables

I am trying to install anaconda version anaconda 3 -2019-07 -64 on my window 10 what i noticed was after few minutes of starting installation i can see the icon of anaconda navigator , spyder , jyupter in my start menu but as the installation process continues it shows that an error occurred while installing package file not found ( the system cannot find the specified file none,2,none ) attempting to roll back and  Path not writable or missing. environment location
and then all the icon of spyder navigator etc disappear and i am not able to find them anywhere in my entire computer . i have reinstalled it several times and also tried previous version but still same error shows .
plz help........ 
here is the error

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(637): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: ...working... DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3', env_name: 'Anaconda3', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\spyder-script.py', '--reset']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3', env_name: 'Anaconda3', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\python.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py', '"%USERPROFILE%/"']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3', env_name: 'Anaconda3', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe, args are ['C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\cwp.py', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\anaconda-navigator-script.py']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3', env_name: 'Anaconda3', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is %windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe, args are ['-ExecutionPolicy', 'ByPass', '-NoExit', '-Command', '"& \'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1\' ; conda activate \'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\' "']
DEBUG menuinst_win32:__init__(199): Menu: name: 'Anaconda${PY_VER} ${PLATFORM}', prefix: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3', env_name: 'Anaconda3', mode: 'user', used_mode: 'user'
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(324): Shortcut cmd is %windir%\System32\cmd.exe, args are ['"/K"', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat', 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\Anaconda3']
done

[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
()

Delete file: C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pkgs\env.txt
Output folder: C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\conda-meta
Extract: history
Creating Anaconda3 menus...
Execute: "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" mkdirs
Running post install...
Execute: "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" post_install
Execute: "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Lib\_nsis.py" addpath 3.7.3 Anaconda3 2019.07 64-bit
Execute: "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\pkgs\.cio-config.py" "C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\Anaconda3-2019.07-Windows-x86_64.exe"
Created uninstaller: C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe
Completed
```

Answer (score 0):

FileNotFoundError is a result of not finding the file qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0. You can try this work around.

step 1: Go to this [webpage](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/qt/files?sort=time&sort_order=desc&version=5.9.7&channel=main) and download the tarball(win-64/qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0.tar.bz2).

step 2: create a folder Anaconda3, you might already have this folder it will be the same directory as when you install Anaconda3.

step 3: in the Anaconda3 folder make a pkgs folder.

step 4: paste your tarball into Anaconda3\pkgs

step 5: reinstall Anaconda3 in the same directory where you made your Anaconda3 folder.

I don't know if this will work but its worth a shot, if there's a prompt to overwrite or merge, or something like that, pick merge you don't want to erase the tarball you just installed. If it does work you might get an error about another FileNotFound. But at least we'll have made progress. Let me know what happens thanks.

Comment: if i try to reinstall at the same directory it shows that it is not empty please choose a different location

Comment: okay keep it empty for now, and run the installation, 
once you choose your directory, another setup prompt appears "Advanced Installation Options" with two check boxes. Don't click anything yet. You can now add the file and directory. then proceed with install.

Comment: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
Attempting to roll back.

Comment: ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_post_link_actions(720): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::ipykernel-5.1.2-py37h39e3cac_0'.
FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)
Attempting to roll back.

WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(46): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3
  registry file: C:\Users\Lenovo\.conda\environments.txt
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(637): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'

Comment: plz help i need to install anaconda soon

Comment: Add a new folder in C:\Users\Lenovo called .conda so you should have C:\Users\Lenovo\.conda then run the installation again.

Comment: Did you get Anaconda installed at all?

Comment: yes it gets installed  i can see it in settings but spyder and packages cannot be find

Comment: uninstall anaconda, and try doing a fresh install.  make sure you have the \.conda folder as stated above and install anaconda in the same directory as your \.conda folder.

Comment: check your directory for these files: ~\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe ~\Anaconda3\cwp.py ~\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe ~\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py if you have them then you have anaconda navigator. Click on ~\Anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator to start the application.